# Javascript - search a string from beginning

Tags: javascript

Hello i currently have this part of the code that i developed but i want to do some edits:

```
$('#target').keydown(function(event) {
 if (event.which == 13) 
 {
    var users = ["Dennis Lucky","Lucy Foo","Name Lastname","Billy Jean"];
    var match = 0;
    var str = $('#target').val();

    for(i=0;i<users.length;i++)
    {
        if ( users[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) > -1 )
        {
            match++;
            name = users[i];
        }
    }
    if(match == 1)
    {
        $('#target').val('');
        $('#chatbox').append('<span style="color:blue;">'+name+'</span>&nbsp;');
        console.log(name);
    }
    else if (match >= 2)
    {
        console.log("many entries");
    }
 }});
```

The idea is that if i type something and hit enter if the partial string exists in users becomes blue color.With this code i have the problem that if i write "Lu" i get 2 results, "Dennis Lucky" and "Lucy Foo".

I want to change my code so when i type "Lu" it will start searching the words starting with this sting and not include it.

Comment: Split the names and check index of is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( users[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) > -1 )
```

The condition is true if indexOf's returned value is greater than -1.  In JavaScript, indexOf returns -1 if a match "needle" (the string you're searching for) isn't found in your "haystack" (the string that you're searching within).  Otherwise, it returns the first index of the "needle" in your "haystack".

To explain my terminology of indexOf, here's an example:

```
haystack.indexOf(needle); // How to use the indexOf function
console.log("apples oranges apples".indexOf("apples")); // This would print 0.
console.log("apples oranges apples".indexOf("white")); // This would print -1.
```

If you want to ensure that the string starts with the "needle", you simply need to change your code to

```
    if ( users[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) == 0 )
```

If you want your "words" ("Lucy Foo" would be "Lucy" and "Foo"), either split your name strings by a space character and perform the indexof search with the elements of the resultant array, or turn to regex.

Comment: It's supposed to be "Lucy Foo" as Name Lastname so the == 0 in my if statement works great!  I find regex too complicated you saved me a lot of trouble :)

Comment: While more complicated eventually you'll have to suck it up and learn them. Here's a link to an online regex tester to help with debugging/writing. http://regexpal.com/ and http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use regexes. Since you want to search the start of string use `^`

Refer [Regular Expressions documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more information.